# Unit testing Zsh completion script

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to write a completion script for Zsh. I'd like to unit test the completion script. For example, I'd like to test that completions for `my-command --h` include `--help`.

For Fish, I can use [`complete -C 'my-command --h'`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/complete.html), which would then output `--help` and any other valid completions.

I can't seem to find an equivalent command for Zsh. Does one exist? I've tried things like `_main_complete`, `_complete` and `_normal`, but either they don't support this or I'm not invoking them in the correct way (I get a lot of `can only be called from completion function` errors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get a lot of `can only be called from completion function errors`

This is because Zsh's completion commands can run only from inside a completion widget, which in turn can only be called while the Zsh Line Editor is active. We can work around this by activating a completion widget on an active command line inside a so-called [pseudo terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal):

```sh
# Set up your completions as you would normally.
compdef _my-command my-command
_my-command () {
        _arguments '--help[display help text]'  # Just an example.
}

# Define our test function.
comptest () {
        # Gather all matching completions in this array.
        # -U discards duplicates.
        typeset -aU completions=()  

        # Override the builtin compadd command.
        compadd () {
                # Gather all matching completions for this call in $reply.
                # Note that this call overwrites the specified array.
                # Therefore we cannot use $completions directly.
                builtin compadd -O reply "$@"

                completions+=("$reply[@]") # Collect them.
                builtin compadd "$@"       # Run the actual command.
        }

        # Bind a custom widget to TAB.
        bindkey "^I" complete-word
        zle -C {,,}complete-word
        complete-word () {
                # Make the completion system believe we're on a normal 
                # command line, not in vared.
                unset 'compstate[vared]'

                _main_complete "$@"  # Generate completions.

                # Print out our completions.
                # Use of ^B and ^C as delimiters here is arbitrary.
                # Just use something that won't normally be printed.
                print -n $'\C-B'
                print -nlr -- "$completions[@]"  # Print one per line.
                print -n $'\C-C'
                exit
        }

        vared -c tmp
}

zmodload zsh/zpty  # Load the pseudo terminal module.
zpty {,}comptest   # Create a new pty and run our function in it.

# Simulate a command being typed, ending with TAB to get completions.
zpty -w comptest $'my-command --h\t'

# Read up to the first delimiter. Discard all of this.
zpty -r comptest REPLY $'*\C-B'

zpty -r comptest REPLY $'*\C-C'  # Read up to the second delimiter.

# Print out the results.
print -r -- "${REPLY%$'\C-C'}"   # Trim off the ^C, just in case.

zpty -d comptest  # Delete the pty.
```

Running the example above will print out:

```
--help
```

If you want to test the entire completion output and not just the strings that would be inserted on the command line, then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/668618/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-zsh-completion/668827#668827

Comment: This works well from the command line, but from a script, putting `compdef _my-command my-command` inside `comptest()`, I get no result. Do you know if this could be automated? Ideally, I'd like to use this with ShellSpec.

Comment: My guess is that, when running this from a non-interactive session, you will need to move _all_ of the required code into `comptest()`, including a call to `compinit` and the function definition of `my-command`. If that doesn't work, please open a new question. 